# Adding CSS class names to comments_popup_link in WordPress theme.

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm currently trying to style up a Wordpress theme, I don't have the greatest PHP knowledge but it's going pretty good so far.

My one question is, how can I add classes and ID's to hook my CSS to? For example:

The code to generate the 'leave a comment' link on each post is:

```
<?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
```

I want to style this, it displays out as a link, but obviously I can't change the CSS simply for every `a` tag in my main column. I need to add some sort of class to hook on to.

How do I do this?

```
<?php class="commentLnk" comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
```

^ Guessing that isn't right at all.

Comment: You need to find the 'comments_popup_link' function and allow it to accept and use the parameters you choose.

Comment: @Diodeus where abouts would I find that, and what would I need to use to allow it to accept these parameters? Is there an easier way to specify without using CSS? Best way to style it?

Comment: I don't know Wordpress' inner workings, but chances are that it already provides meaningful classes and IDs. Maybe you could just override those in your CSS. Have a look at the page source maybe?

Comment: @jordi12100 don't down vote, EDIT!

Comment: @Diodeus is incorrect - you don't have to modify the function at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own CSS style classes to the comments link.

> comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'cssclass');

As explained in the WordPress API documentation for the [commands_popup_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link).

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick:

```
<span class="commentLnk"><?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></span>
```

Alternatively, the function also accepts a fourth parameter which will be used as the class:

```
<?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'commentLnk'); ?>
```